# Bootstrap elements on left and right ends

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a filter form at the top which looks like this

[image: Desktop Layout]

and like this in the Mobile Layout
[image: Mobile Layout]

This is my code

```
<form class="navbar-form " role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group ">
            Results per page:
            <select class="form-control" name="perpage" id="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
               <option value="5" selected="">5</option>
               <option value="10">10</option>
               <option value="20">20</option>
               <option value="50">50</option>
               <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="resetform()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

What can I do with this? I would like it if the search box and the 2 buttons come beside it on the same line without being floated to right but the mobile layout is all messed up. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="navbar-form " role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group ">
                Results per page:
                <select class="form-control" name="perpage" id="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                   <option value="5" selected="">5</option>
                   <option value="10">10</option>
                   <option value="20">20</option>
                   <option value="50">50</option>
                   <option value="100">100</option>
                </select>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword" value="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="resetform()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you all for your answers. I have upvoted the answers that helped me get what I wanted. However, I ended up doing something of my own.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword" value="<?php echo ($this->input->get('search',true)); ?>">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="resetform()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change to only **"col-sm-6"** and the class named "pull-right" and add "float-right". 
Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ceqvpu01/1/

```
input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .float-right{
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

set `width:auto;display: inline-block;` to input text field

check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30416/

Comment: Thanks! This works!! Is there any way I can make the text box take the remaining full width?

Comment: This is breaking the desktop version...cannot use this!

Comment: what is it breaking ?. you have to tweak a little with css.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you put the 'col-xs-12' on both form. so each form will takes all of the grid system (12) and the second form will be put below the first because there is no more grid for it. try changing your col-xs-12 to col-xs-6 for both form

Comment: Hi @danny, thank you for your answer! However, I want them to come one below the other in mobile devices. But the problem is that it is being dragged to the right end and in 2 lines instead of 1 line!

Comment: so you want them (search keyword, go , reset) to be in the left? notice that you use pull-right in the div class above. maybe thats the problem why they are being dragged to the right

Comment: I want all 3 elements in the same 2nd line and one after the another!

Comment: @Arcanyx if set width to auto and display to inline block works for you but not for your desktop version you need to use css media queries . put it all inside a media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I added `col-sm-6` to both, and changed `col-xs-12` to `col-xs-6`

```
<form class="navbar-form " role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
         <div class="form-group ">
            Results per page:
            <select class="form-control" name="perpage" id="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
               <option value="5" selected="">5</option>
               <option value="10">10</option>
               <option value="20">20</option>
               <option value="50">50</option>
               <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
         <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="resetform()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope. That did not do any thing different!

Comment: Even when you resize the browser? For me it works. both stay aligned to each other

Comment: You forgot to change `col-xs-12` to `col-xs-6`

Comment: I see, you wish to make the search and the buttons to go down but not to right end and in two lines. I misunderstood your question